# Why does jQuery's val() strip carriage return?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the jQuery docs, it is mentioned that

> At present, using .val() on textarea elements strips carriage return characters from the browser-reported value. When this value is sent to the server via XHR however, carriage returns are preserved (or added by browsers which do not include them in the raw value). A workaround for this issue can be achieved using a valHook as follows:

1. Why does jQuery's val() strip carriage return?
2. It seems that in Windows, textarea newlines are represented by \n. In Mac is it represented by \r? If so would stripping \r cause a problem?
3. What does it mean when the docs say "via XHR however, carriage returns are preserved"?

Answer (score 0):

I got this from this link http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/9007 and make some sense...

> When asked for the value of a textarea element, the ".val()" code
>   strips all carriage return characters from the browser-reported value.
>
> However, when the value is submitted to the server, carriage returns
>   are preserved (or added, by browsers that don't include them in the
>   raw value), and (since #6876) jQuery makes sure they're there in the
>   serialized version for XHR(**XMLHttpRequest** is an API available to web browser scripting languages such as JavaScript. It is used to send HTTP or HTTPS requests to a web server and load the server response data back into the script) purposes.
>
> The problem with the discrepancy between the field as reported by
>   ".val()" and the actual submitted content is that when providing a
>   sort of "maxlength" facility to report on available characters in a
>   textarea, that code must account for the difference in cases where the
>   carriage returns are preserved at the server (in my experience, a very
>   likely thing). In other words, the "character countdown" must take
>   into account the fact that when the textarea value (as reported by
>   jQuery) contains newlines, then its actual length where it matters --
>   at the database, or in server-side validation code -- is greater by
>   the number of newlines.
>
> Now obviously this math is easy to do, and there may be all sorts of
>   virtue in stripping those carriage returns. The behavior is not
>   documented clearly, as far as I can tell; it's certainly absent from
>   the description of ".val()". My observation is that in fact this
>   discrepancy is unknown to many authors of exactly the sort of facility
>   I described above.

Hope this helps to understand this behavior.